# Problema con dos condiciones de .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Tenía estas condiciones en el archivo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

No lo hice yo, lo copie de un foro y sirve para quitar las extensiones de la barra de navegación `.php` y me funcionaba ahora agregue otra directiva

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /error404.php [L]
```

Según entiendo es para redireccionar a una página si apache no encuentra la que pedí, pero ya dejó de funcionar todo el sitio. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que en el mismo archivo convivan las dos instrucciones

> Borrar la extensión .php de la barra de navegación
>
> Redirigir a una página hecha si la ruta que el cliente pide no existe

También si me pueden explicar para que sirve cada instrucción estaría fenomenal por que no entiendo nada.

Comment: probaste con `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php` ? [ref](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html)

Comment: A decir verdad, no entiendo mucho de instrucciones a Apache.

Comment: la primera parte se traduce a si lo que piden (+.php) es un archivo (file, -f) entonces servir loquepiden.php, la segunda parte es mas rara dice si "loquepiden" no es un directorio/carpeta (! not -d directorio) reemplazar "loquepiden" por (y servir) /error404.php . si queres mostrar/servir un archivo en especial cuando hay un 404 la directiva ErrorDocument es la q va

Comment: Una pregunta, cuando agregaste la nueva directiva ¿pegaste solo las 2 lineas que mencionas debajo de las que ya estaban?

Comment: Si, solo vi para que servian las otras dos directivas y las pegue sin más, pero dejó de funcionar,como hago lo del ErrorDocument

Comment: si pedis un css o jpg no activa la primera regla, se activa la segunda y si error404.php pide un css vuelve a circular. el `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php` lo pones en el `virtualhost` o en el `.htaccess`, en el primer comentario hay un enlace al manual donde podes ver todas las opciones. podes poner un `.html` estático con css y svg inline (asi no anda pidiendo otros files) para los error 500 por ejemplo ( vuelca php y no se ve tan feo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta reemplazar tu archivo `.htaccess` con estas lineas:

```
# En el caso que no se encuetre un archivo, redireccionamos
# (IMPORTANTE!: reemplazar [DOMINIO] por el path completo al archivo error404.php)
ErrorDocument 404 http://[DOMINIO]/error404.php

RewriteEngine On

# ENLACES A ARCHIOS PHP SIN EXTENSION
# Si no es archivo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# y no es directorio
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# y si existe "{file}.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# entonces reescribimos la URL y le agregamos ".php"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, podrías decirme de donde podría sacar más información de las instrucciones para Apache un poco más digeridas que la documentación oficial?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Te recomiendo [visitar esta página](https://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/) (en ingles)

Comment: @Marcos esta línea de htaccess RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  me ha causado problemas, es necesario ponerla o la puedo omitir??

Comment: El problema esta en que la ruta que pongo en la petición ajax no la encuentra por ejemplo: url_base() + "/acciones.contacto/registrar"

Comment: @Marcos [http://localhost/misitio]

Comment: @Marcos asi es como tengo definida la ruta /misitio/acciones.contacto/registrar y como te digo solo funciona si en el htaccess quito la linea que te comente

Comment: @JorgeAlonso hice [esta prueba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zio7N.png) y si me funciona.

Comment: @Marcos algun correo a donde pueda mandarte imagenes o el proyecto como tal para que lo analices

Comment: @Marcos https://github.com/alex0190/Agenda, ahi esta mi proyecto, agradeceria mucho que pudieras ayudarme

Comment: @JorgeAlonso, ya veo porque no te sirve. Vos tenes tu propio router, necesitas otro tipo de `.htaccess`. Dejame que hago un PR con otras propuestas

Comment: @Marcos claro, espero tu respuesta

Comment: @JorgeAlonso, por las dudas, te paso el [link al PR](https://github.com/alex0190/Agenda/pull/1). Espero te sirva.